# Proper usage windows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working on my first Cocoa Mac OS X program and wondering the best approach to showing the windows.

I have my `AppController` / `MainMenu.xib` as the main launch window but have the MainMenu.xib window unchecked for **Visible At Launch**. I do this because on application load I am checking to see if they are logged in. If not I want to display the `Login.xib` window instead of the `MainMenu.xib`. Once logged in, I would open the `MainMenu.xib` window and close the `LoginController` I have this in the `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"app delegate");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];
    BOOL didAuth = NO;
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMClasses authForService];
    if (auth) {
        didAuth = [GTMOAuth2WindowController authorizeFromKeychainForName:kKeychainName authentication:auth];
    }

    if (didAuth) {
        [[DataClass sharedInstance] setIsSignedIn:YES];
        NSLog(@"Already signed in %@", auth);
        NSLog(@"Window: %@", self.window);
        // SHOW MainMenu.xib here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not signed in %@", auth);
        loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Login" owner:self];
        [[loginController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    }
}
```

1. I see that AppController's `awakeFromNib` gets called before the `applicationDidFinishLoadingWithOptions`. Would it be best to put that code in my `awakeFromNib`?
2. If not, what is the best way to open the MainMenu.xib window from the AppDelegate?
3. If you have a better approach, what would it be?

PS: AppController is a subclass of `NSObject` so I don't have access to `windowDidLoad` or `windowWillLoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is the first method to get executed.

You can also use `alloc` or `init` methods.

You can put your login authentication codes there, without any problem.

You must have seen the application life-cycle, how and when what methods get loaded.

[image]

Comment: So are you saying I should move my code from above into the AppController init or awakeFromNib?